# Blue Prism, regarding SqlServerExpress

Tags: sql, sql-server, blueprism

I have two set up files for SQLServer

> 1. SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr  5Mb
> 2. SSMS-Setup-ENU 540 Mb

Which file need to be installed.

If the setup file need to be installed then what is the use for the first one?

can  someone please advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr is an installation package for installation of SQL Server Express binaries required to run the database server. You must install it to have your server.

SSMS-Setup-ENU is an installation package for GUI client which allows you to connect to SQL Server database instance and manage it. Although it's not required to be installed on the machine with running SQL Server it's recommended to be installed on administration/developer machine to interact with the database using T-SQL.